# When are these irreducible complex representations for the Type D Weyl group self-dual?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

Given an integer $n \geq 4$, consider the Weyl groups $W(B_n)$ and $W(D_n)$ of types $B_n$ and $D_n$, respectively, and consider their representation theory over the field of complex numbers.

The Weyl group $W(B_n)$ is the wreath product $C_2 \wr S_n = C_2^n \rtimes S_n$ of the cyclic group $C_2 = \{\pm 1\}$ and the symmetric group $S_n$. It is well-known that the irreducible $W(B_n)$-modules are parameterized by bi-partitions $(\lambda,\mu)$ of $n$, i.e., ordered pairs of partitions $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that $|\lambda|+|\mu| = n$. One can show that if $V = V^{(\lambda,\mu)}$ is the irreducible $W(B_n)$-module labeled by the bi-partition $(\lambda,\mu)$, then the dual module $V^* = \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V,\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $V^{(\lambda',\mu')}$, where $\lambda'$ and $\mu'$ are the transpose (or conjugate) partitions associated to $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively. In particular, $V \cong V^*$ if and only if $\lambda = \lambda'$ and $\mu = \mu'$.

The Weyl group $W(D_n)$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $\xi: W(B_n) = C_2^n \rtimes S_n \to \{\pm 1\}$ that is trivial on $S_n$ and that acts on $\mathbb{Z}_2^n = \{\pm 1\}^n$ by multiplying all of the factors together. In particular, $W(D_n)$ is an index-$2$ subgroup of $W(B_n)$. Since $V^{(\lambda,\mu)} \otimes \xi \cong V^{(\mu,\lambda)}$ as $W(B_n)$-modules, one then gets the following via classical Clifford theory:

1. If $\lambda \neq \mu$, then $V^{(\lambda,\mu)}$ and $V^{(\mu,\lambda)}$ are isomorphic and irreducible as $W(D_n)$-modules.
2. If $(\lambda,\lambda)$ is a bi-partition of $n$, then $V = V^{(\lambda,\lambda)}$ decomposes as a $W(D_n)$-module into a direct sum $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^+} \oplus V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^-}$ of two non-isomorphic, conjugate, irreducible $W(D_n)$-modules.
3. Every irreducible $W(D_n)$-module is uniquely of one of the preceding forms, subject only to the $W(D_n)$-module isomorphism $V^{(\lambda,\mu)} \cong V^{(\mu,\lambda)}$ if $\lambda \neq \mu$.

**I would like to know when an irreducible $W(D_n)$-module is self-dual.** The only case where there seems to be some ambiguity is when $n$ is even, for irreducibles of the forms $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^+}$ and $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^-}$ with $\lambda = \lambda'$. In this case $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)}$ is self-dual as a $W(B_n)$-module, so it follows that either $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^+}$ and $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^-}$ are each self-dual as $W(D_n)$-modules, or one of them is isomorphic to the dual of the other.

**Given a symmetric partition $\lambda$, is there a criterion, depending on the shape of the Young diagram of $\lambda$, for deciding whether $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^+}$ and $V^{(\lambda,\lambda)^-}$ are each self-dual?**

An analogous situation occurs when looking at the irrreducible representations of the alternating group $A_n$. If $\lambda = \lambda'$, then the Specht module $S^\lambda$ decomposes into a direct sum $S^{\lambda^+} \oplus S^{\lambda^-}$ of two irreducible $A_n$-modules. These modules are self-dual if and only if their corresponding complex characters are real-valued. There are explicit formulas for the values of these characters (see for example Theorem 2.5.13 in James and Kerber's book *The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group*, or Proposition 5.3 in Fulton and Harris' book *Representation Theory*), from which one can see that the characters will both be real-valued if and only if the number of squares above the diagonal in the Young diagram of $\lambda$ is even.

Comment: Am I missing some point? I thought that all Weyl groups were rational, so, in particular, real-valued ( see the answers to the question MR134581, for example). Note that the example of $A_{n}$ is different in the sense that $A_{n}$ is not itself a Weyl group.

Comment: I was not aware of that fact about Weyl groups, but I now realize I should have been, because it's mentioned in one of the first references I looked at (in Section 8.10 of Humphreys' book *Reflection groups and Coxeter groups*). Thank you for pointing this out! That wraps up my question.

Comment: I realize now that I was confused on several points when formulating this question. For example, the statement I made about dual modules being labeled by transpose partitions is not true. What I was actually interested in, and what I was probably thinking of when writing the question, was tensoring a module with the sign representation.

Comment: I must admit that statement about the Cliffor theory confused me, since I knew that Weyl groups had all irreducible characters  real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, all irreducible characters of Weyl groups are rational, and, in particular, real.